# How to refer to a relative path in SolidWorks VBA

Tags: vba, excel, solidworks

I am writing a macro in SolidWorks VBA that is supposed to open all the parts of an assembly and update their design tables. When the assembly and parts are copied to a new location, I want the macro to open the new (copied) parts in their new location. How do I refer to a relative path for the parts instead of an absolute path.

Or: How do I program VBA to change the file location of the parts to the current folder?

I've found some info on how this works in Excel VBA, yet I can't seem to translate this to SolidWorks VBA.

`Dim folderpath As String`
`folderpath = Application.Activeworkbook.Path`

I can't figure out with what I should replace "ActiveWorkbook" to get the location of the current assembly. Searching the object browser in SW VBA doesn't show anything usefull either.

Comment: Strange, why was this question upvoted? No efforts from the TO, just a request for code.

Comment: @Storax I'm sorry, I'm new to VBA and with my limited knowledge I can't make it work. I don't want the code, I want to find out how it works.

Comment: That's ok, but maybe you can try to improve your question by adding more information. You found code that works in Excel VBA. You could have posted that and then you could aks a specific question how to "translate" it to SolidWorks VBA. But anyway, I am still astonished that the question was upvoted.

Comment: @Storax I've edited my question, thanks for the feedback

Comment: A google search is saying `swModel.GetPathName` could be what you are looking for in case `swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc ` and `swApp = Application.SldWorks `

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `swModel.GetPathName`. [Here's an example.](http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/api/sldworksapi/get_paths_of_open_documents_example_vb.htm?verRedirect=1)